# How to represent nested data in Firebase class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Taken from the Firebase example, if I have a Dinosaurs facts data structure like this:

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "name": "lamby",
    "work": "eat",
    "dimensions": {
      "height" : 2.1,
      "length" : 12.5,
      "weight": 5000
    }
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "name": "stego",
    "work": "play",
    "dimensions": {
      "height" : 4,
      "length" : 9,
      "weight" : 2500
    }
  }
}
```

How can I represent this structure in a Android Class for Firebase to cast from `DataSnapshot.getValue(DinosaurFacts.class)`?

name, and work are represented as Strings, but how to represent "dimensions" collection in the class?

Also how can I access data values from `DataSnapshot` about height & weight?

**EDIT**
I can get the individual elements looping through the snapshot, but am trying to find how to represent the data in the class structure.

```
for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Log.d("hz-key:", child.getKey().toString());
                Log.d("hz-val:", child.getValue().toString());
            }
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: yes I can get the individual data using dataSnapshot.getChildren -> get value and key. But am wondering how to represent the nested structure in my java class directly. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The JavaBean class to represent this structure is:

```
public static class DinosaurFacts {
    String name;
    String work;
    Dimensions dimensions;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getWork() {
        return work;
    }

    public Dimensions getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }

    public class Dimensions {
        double height;
        long weight;
        double length;

        public double getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public long getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public double getLength() {
            return length;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can read a dino with:

```
DinosaurFacts dino = dinoSnapshot.getValue(DinosaurFacts.class);
```

And access the dimensions with for example:

```
dino.getDimensions().getWeight();
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Yes this way with individual classes I can encapsulate all my custom structures cleanly.

Comment: what if one of my child properties is an array of integers? Would I use List<Integer> array to retrieve the data? I know that firebase stores array data as an object, but how do I convert that to a java property?

Comment: Note that the subclass needs to be declared static if it has a constructor, otherwise it will result in "...is missing a constructor with no arguments" (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39087010/1004331)

Comment: Wha if dimensions had multiple dimension properties? like dimensions: { dimension1: { "height" : 4,"length" : 9,"weight" : 2500 },dimension2: { "height" : 4,"length" : 9,"weight" : 2500 },dimension3: { "height" : 4,"length" : 9,"weight" : 2500 }}

Answer (score 0):

I followed Frank's answer but I got an error that says:

> subclass needs an empty constructor

even though I had one.

**Solution:**

Create a new (**outer**) class for it.

---

**Here is my example:**

**1st Class:**

```
public class Event {

    private String name;
    private Place place;
}
```

**Sub Class:**

```
public class Place {

     private String name;
     private Location location;

}
```

**Sub of Sub Class:**

```
public class Location {

     private String city;
     private Double longitude, latitude;

}
```

Comment: Yes you need to have an empty constructor for the firebase data class to work. Also the class needs to be serializable.