# Firebase "User is missing a constructor with no arguments"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve my user details from the /User/ tree i have in Firebase.  I have the following User object :

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private String lastOnline;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private ArrayList<SwapLocation> locations;

    public User(){ }

    public String getName(){
        if(firebaseUser.getDisplayName() != null && !firebaseUser.getDisplayName().equals(""))
            return firebaseUser.getDisplayName();

        if(name != null && !name.equals(""))
            return name;

        return "";
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        if(firebaseUser.getEmail() != null && firebaseUser.getEmail().equals(""))
            return firebaseUser.getEmail();

        if(email != null && email.equals(""))
            return email;

        return "";
    }
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser firebaseUser){
        this.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;  
    }
    public FirebaseUser getFirebaseUser(){
        return firebaseUser;
    }

    public void setLastOnline(String lastOnline){
        this.lastOnline = lastOnline;
    }
    public String getLastOnline(){
        if(lastOnline != null)
            return lastOnline;

        return "";
    }

    public void setLatLong(LatLng latlng){
        this.latLng = latlng;
    }
    public LatLng getLatLong(){
        return this.latLng;
    }

    public ArrayList<SwapLocation> getLocations(){
        return locations;
    }
    public void setLocations(ArrayList<SwapLocation> locations){
        this.locations = locations;
    } 
}
```

I am trying to retrieve this object from Firebase.  The object is retrieved in the dataSnapshot, although it has a problem serializing to my User object.

This is how i am retrieving the object from Firebase:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(users_group).child(user.getUid());
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User this_user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); 
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
            });
```

But when trying to do 'User this_user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)' i get an error saying "User is missing a constructor with no arguments"

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: I can't explain why you are getting the "missing constructor" error.  But I doubt Firebase will be able to serialize/deserialize your `User` class if `FirebaseUse`r is not a simple POJO you defined and instead is actually `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser`.  That class not a simple POJO and almost certainly has features that the Firebase serializer is not designed to handle.

Comment: A quick guess is that your `User` class is defined inside another class. If that is the case, mark it as static: `static public class User {`. In addition, as qbix commented, I doubt `FirebaseUser` meets the database requirements for serialization (would be kinda cool if it did), so you'll have to `@Exclude` that.

Comment: Ah damn, that sucks because i only want one User object.  It seems like I need two objects, one FirebaseUser and one User for the additional properties (because the user can login without a 3rd party Auth, so those details, such as name, phone etc, need to be stored somewhere, in the 'users' tree).  

Or the alternative is to store the FirebaseUser in my Users object and strip it from the User object when doing calls to Firebase.. hmm what do you guys think the best solution would be?

Answer (score 81):

I have faced this in **kotlin** with firebase realtime database and solve it by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134217/8874958)

For Kotlin, if you're using data class like below for firebase,

```
data class UserModel(
        var UserName: String,
        var UserType: Int
)
```

then you'll get an error like

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: UserModel does not
>   define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure
>   these constructors are not stripped.

So for this, you need to initialize its values.

```
data class UserModel(
        var UserName: String = "",
        var UserType: Int = 0
)
```

Answer (score 38):

You must be getting this error because your User class is a sub class.

## Solution:

Either mark your class static:

```
 public class SomeParentClass{ 

        public static class User {
            ....
        }
    }
```

**or create it in a separate file.**

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. The error message is tricky, since you get it whether or not your constructors include one with no arguments for whatever class you created for the database, if you define the class generically in your main activity as I originally did. The message implies an issue with the class definition, rather than the real issue of where and how it was defined.

Answer (score 4):

The User has no arguments error means that even though you do need an empty constructor:

```
public User(){ }
```

You will also need another constructor with the variables that are children in your object in Firebase inside of the constructor. For instance:

```
 public User(
      String name,
      String email,
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser,
      String lastOnline,
      LatLng latLng,
      ArrayList<SwapLocation> locations
 ){
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
      this.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
      this.lastOnline = lastOnline;
      this.latLong = latLong;
      this.locations = locations;
 }
```

Also be careful with classes inside of the constructors such as `SwapLocation`, if it is not automatically parsed, you need to modify it the same way.

In the other hand, in Kotlin you should not instantiate with empty values, instead you should instantiate with null and add `@IgnoreExtraProperties` and `@Keep` on top to load attributes only if they exist in the data. For instance:

```
@Keep
@IgnoreExtraProperties
open class User(
     var name : String? = null,
     var email : String? = null,
     var firebaseUser : FirebaseUser? = null,
     var lastOnline : String? = null,
     var latLng : LatLng? = null,
     var locations : ArrayList<SwapLocation>? = null
)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

in kotlin it is need to initialized data class contructor variable to dignose this error.

```
data class Images(val imageOne:String="",
                  val imageTwo:String="",
                  val imageThree:String=""
)
```

Comment: For Kotlin this is solution