# How can I serialize my User class for the Firebase Database and fix this error?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the updated User from the dataSnapshot of the Firebase Database:

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User atualizedUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            fName.setText(atualizedUser.getFirstName());
            lName.setText(atualizedUser.getLastName());
            profilePhoto.setProfileId(atualizedUser.getProfileId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

But I get this error below:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class bqs.bomqueso.Model.User is missing a constructor with no arguments
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zzaH(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                            at bqs.bomqueso.Activities.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Here my User class (this is not a subclass, I created it in a separate file):

```
public class User {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String profileId;

public User() { }

    public User(String fName, String lName, String id) {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.profileId = id;
    }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String id) { 
        this.profileId = id; 
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lName) { 
        this.lastName = lName; 
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) { 
        this.firstName = fName; 
    }
}
```

I find similar questions here, but I hadn't found a solution for my problem, I hope you guys can help me, Thank you in advance!

Comment: `User is missing a constructor with no arguments`... This doesn't match your code... You do have `public User() { }`

Comment: I don't know why I'm having this error, because, as you said I do have a constructor with no arguments, any hints?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 36):

For **Kotlin**, if you're using data class like below for firebase,

```
data class UserModel(
        var userName: String,
        var userType: Int
)
```

then you'll get an error like

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: UserModel does not
>   define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure
>   these constructors are not stripped.

So for this, you **just need to initialize its values**.

```
data class UserModel(
        var userName: String = "",
        var userType: Int = 0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor with no arguments as

public User() { } as cricket mentioned and to serialize

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String profileId;

public User() {
}

public User(String fName, String lName, String id) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.profileId = id;

}
public String getProfileId() {
    return profileId;
}

public void setProfileId(String id) {
    this.profileId = id;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lName) {
    this.lastName = lName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String fName) {
    this.firstName = fName;
}
```

}

If this didn't meet requirement note down

Comment: You duplicated the no-arg constructor

Comment: Now i have corrected My mistake Thanks for the feedback

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question, then?

Comment: What happens if 'android.location.Address' is a type of an attribute in this class, I can't change this class to implement zero argument method, what can I do?