# Create model class and get the data inside the child node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a model class to use it to firebaserecycleradapter but my problem is there is a child node inside a user data. It looks like this
[image]

I need get the following: (name, thumbnail, year, course). This what I have done

```
public class Users {

private String name;
private String thumbnail;

//TODO: need to get the year and course, inside the Student


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}
}
```

How can I get the year and course inside the student

Comment: See my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010429/how-to-represent-nested-data-in-firebase-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the child node data inside a user data That is values inside Student (year, course) you need to make model class like below:

```
 public class User {


    private String name;
    private String thumbnail;
    private Student student;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }


    public class Student {

        private String year;
        private String course;

        public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        public void setYear(String year) {
            this.year = year;
        }

        public String getCourse() {
            return course;
        }

        public void setCourse(String course) {
            this.course = course;
        }

    }
}
```

You can use constructor as well as getter/setter method for the same.

For adding data to model, create object and use set method like below:

```
//Setting Data
User userObj = new User();
userObj.setName("XYZ");
userObj.setThumbnail("URL");

Student student = new User().new Student();
student.setYear("2018");
student.setCourse("MCA");

userObj.setStudent(student);
```

You simply need to assign data to object of model class and the fetch data by using get methods, like this...

```
//Getting Data                           
String name=userObj.getName();
String thumbnail=userObj.getThumbnail();
String year=userObj.getStudent().getYear();
String course=userObj.getStudent().getCourse();
```

Comment: should I add a constructor for both classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a model but you will have another model with the user-id as your class name, so I suggest you to change the structure of the database. You can make it like

`user
     -0
       -Student`

and then you can have List inside your usermodel

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly create two model classes "users" and "Student"**

```
public class users 
{
    public String name;
    public String thumbnail;
    public Student student; 
}


public class Student 
{
    public String course;
    public String year;
}
```

**Now, you have can access the year and course objects of the Student class like this**

```
users u = new users;
String studentYear =  u.student.year;
String studentCourse = u.student.course;
```