# Retrieve a child in a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter using its model

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Let's say I have this structure:

```
{
    "-KuErssnIJU4PBDqCaKf": {
        "c1": "test1",
        "c2": "test2",
        "c3": "test3",
        "users": {
            "VVTHvbILw5hn1LjL6HRcLiZmcmB2": {
                "count": 23
            }
        }
    }
```

To retrieve this example data using Firebase's `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, I must create a model. In this case:

```java
public class User {
    public String c1;
    public String c2;
    public String c3;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String c1, String c2, String c3){
        this.c1= c1;
        this.c2= c2;
        this.c3= c3;
    }

}
```

**However, let's say I want to retrieve the entire `users`. How do I do this?** Will I have to resort to retrieving it using a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` from inside `populateViewHolder`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create model class and get the data inside the child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167080/create-model-class-and-get-the-data-inside-the-child-node)

Comment: the question you linked shows nested classes, but the paths there are all static. In this question you have a dynamic path (the UID), which is not handled by the Firebase JSON-to-Java conversion automatically. You'll either need to use the raw `DataSnapshot` in the FirebaseUI adapter, or create your own adapter.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry, I didn't quite get what you mean by "Use the raw `DataSnapshot` in the FirebaseUI adapter." You mean I should just call for a valueeventlistener?

Comment: Neh, you don't need a custom listener, since all data is already being loaded. It's just that the default Firebase JSON-to-Java doesn't know how to handle the children of the `users` property. So you'll want to implement a custom `SnapshotParser` that can then (as shown in the second snippet [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter)) to extract the data out of the snapshot.