# getting error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to retrieve users saved data and display it in their profile page using a recycler view. When I run my app to see if everything is working fine but my app keeps crasheing and stops working. The error that I'm given is `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String`. I've got this towork before but I'm not sure what the problem is now. Can anyone help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance. [Updated database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDet6.png)

Image adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<UserInformation> users;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserInformation> uploads){
        mContext = context;
        users = uploads;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View V = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(V);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //String uploadCurrent=users.get(position).getmImageUrl();

        holder.txt1.setText(users.get(position).getAction());
        Picasso.get().load(users.get(position).getmImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();

    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView txt1;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            //txt1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.action);
        }
    }
}
```

Model class

```
  public UserInformation(String  mImageUrl,  String cate, String action, String headline, String websiteurl) {

        this.mImageUrl =  mImageUrl;
        this.cate = cate;
        this.action = action;
        this.headline = headline;
        this.websiteurl = websiteurl;

    }

    public UserInformation() {

    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }


    public String getCategory() {
        return cate;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.cate = cate;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String header) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public String getWebsiteurl() {
        return websiteurl;
    }

    public void setWebsiteurl(String websiteurl) {
        this.websiteurl = websiteurl;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
myUploads = new ArrayList<UserInformation>();
aAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ProfileActivity.this, myUploads);
recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

h=new Handler();

databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
t=findViewById(R.id.none);

    databaseReference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UserInformation upload=postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);


                myUploads.add(upload);
                 aAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ProfileActivity.this, myUploads);
                 recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);

            }
```

Comment: Add the database screen shot to your question, not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your reading code boils down to:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

databaseReference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            UserInformation upload=postsnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);


            myUploads.add(upload);
             aAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ProfileActivity.this, myUploads);
             recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);

        }
```

This means that you're attaching a listener to `/Users/$uid` in the database, and that your `onDataChange` will be called with a data snapshot for a single user.

In that case you don't need to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()` in the `onDataChange`, as you've already targeted the listener to read a single snapshot at an exact path. So:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

databaseReference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        UserInformation upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);

        myUploads.add(upload);
        aAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ProfileActivity.this, myUploads);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: van Puffen thanks for replying. I followed what you told me to do, but now nothing like the image thats was saved is not displaying its just a cardview with nothing

Comment: Which is better than a crash, so I'd consider that process.  :)    If you want to see if the code change works, put a breakpoint on the line `UserInformation upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class)` between your original code and the update. If `upload` has values after that line in the update, it's able to read the values from the database, and the **next** problem is further downstream.

Comment: The way you store `mImageUrl` in the database makes it harder for you to read it back. That's a while separate problem, so I recommend either looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010429/how-to-represent-nested-data-in-firebase-class/33012632#33012632) or opening a new question for specifically that. In general, you should work to isolate your problem so much that my answer is either right or wrong, and not partially right as seems to be the case here.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I'm still having issues with this. The images are not showing, I just get a blank cardview. I even fixed the way stored the mImageUrl part you can look at the updated database above. I'm not sure whats the problem?